# doing a Responsive menu in webpage

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I want to render my menu such that it is responsive on multiple platforms (such as desktop browsers, mobile, and tablets). How can I accomplish this using CSS?

Here's my current CSS:

```css
ul {
 top:0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
 z-index:99;
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color:white;
    text-align:center;
}
li {
 top:0px;
    width:20%;
 font-family:odin rounded;
 font-size:2.5vw;
    float: left;
 height:55px;
 background-color:rgb(240,240,240);
 
 border-right:1px solid black;
 transition:color 1s, background-color 1s;
 
}
li:hover {
 color:white;
 background-color:black;
}

li a {
 
    display: flex;
 display: -webkit-flex;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

img.logo {
 height:55px;
 width:auto;
 position:fixed;
 top:0px;
 z-index:99;
}
.text  {
 display:flex;
 align-items:center;
 text-align:center;
 justify-content: center;
}
a.princip:hover {
 background: transparent url('main.html');
 cursor: pointer;
}
#barre {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  z-index:99;
}

#barre a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#barre a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}




My HTML:
```

```html
<div id="barre">
  <ul >
  <li class="text"><a href="main.html"><img class="logo" src="https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2018/7/18/97bc4958d2a5baf34ad21071a994bb0f-full.png" alt="problem"></a><pre style="font-family:odin rounded">    Team NoMaD</pre></li>
  
  <li class="text" onclick="location.href = 'main.html';">Menu</li> 
  <li class="text" onclick="location.href = 'members.html';">Membres</li> 
  <li class="text" onclick="location.href = 'calender.html';">Calendrier</li>
  <li class="text" onclick="location.href = 'contact.html';">Contact</li>
  
 </ul>
</div>
<script>
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};


var sticky = barre.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    barre.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    barre.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
</script>
<div class="carte">
```

The ideal result (on mobile) is that the menu drop down appears as one line and one square. One of the issues I'm encountering the menu in full-screen isn't in one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your styles

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
    li{
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

With this code you can implement responsive design using nothing but a pure CSS, but I strongly suggest Bootstrap4 and SASS